# Will my Crashed laptop accept Ubuntu

Tags: installation

My laptop has crashed with a million errors and none of the advice i tried seems to work, i was just wondering if i could switch OS from windows to Linux and only use Linux to boot up my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

This should work because Linux will format your entire hard disk.

If you don't mind losing your personal data from Windows, you can switch OS.

You can also use the Live CD to run a temporary Linux system and maybe save your data.

*Edit: By the way, this applies for Windows operating system errors, not for problems with your hardware.*

Comment: But my computer is stuck on the black screen with my emachines logo and booting my Linux disk from the boot menu won't work with an error. i have tried to boot it from WinPE but it won't load as well. Help please. Thanks

Comment: Can you give more information? Which error shows when you want to boot from CD?

Comment: Invalid system disk replace disk and press any key

Comment: Then your Linux CD is the problem. Download a working [Ubuntu Image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?distro=desktop&bits=32&release=lts).